# Не работает скрипт после компиляции через pyinstaller

Tags: python, gui, customtkinter

Есть скрипт на питоне, написан он с использованием customtkinter. Недавно скомпилировал его через Pyinstaller (--onefile) и когда первый раз запустил экзешник увидел:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'customtkinter'[216] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Модуль на компе установлен, обычный main.py запускается безошибочно.
Может я туплю, подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего эта дичь появляется и как ее пофиксить.

Comment: Возможно паинсталлер не находит вашу библиотеку при сборке и нужно явно указать эту библиотеку. Как альтернатива 
 : [костыль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1561798/562052)

Comment: [Рекомендация из официальной документации](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/packaging)