# Как я могу запустить несколько файлов .py параллельно?

Tags: python, exe, объединение, запуск

У меня есть несколько `(5)` пайтон файлов. Они должны работать одновременно.

Я запускаю их следующим образом:

1. кликаю правой кнопкой мыши,
2. edit with IDLE (или что то подобное),
3. в окне с каждым файлом нажимаю "run module" (или что то подобное).

Так каждый файл работает ± параллельно (хотя к сожалению время от времени некоторые зависают, что мешает).

Но я хочу сделать файл, который запустит все остальные в определённой последовательности, однако они все должны работать независимо и параллельно.

Я новичок поэтому заранее извиняюсь за возможно некорректный вопрос. Как я могу это реализовать?

И желательно в итоге запихнуть всё это в `.exe` файл.

Однако мои скрипты создают, и считывают файлы с заданного пути, это не помешает? Библиотеки я тоже использовал.

Если ничего из этого не мешает, то как бы я мог сделать это? Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Сделайте к примеру .bat и запустите все ваши скрипты для начала 

Comment: @Amgarak
я попробовал и сделал бат файл со следующим содержимым "@echo off
python D:\pythonProject\pythonProject6\rec.py %*
python D:\pythonProject\pythonProject6\q.py %*
python D:\pythonProject\pythonProject6\main.py %*
python D:\pythonProject\pythonProject6\vide.py %*
python D:\pythonProject\pythonProject6\go.py %*
pause". не обращайте внимание на названия... запускается только первый скрипт, остальные ждут пока выполнится первый.

Comment: @Amgarak кстати, мне нужно следить за тем что выводят скрипты (имею ввиду, что в скриптах есть "print(что-то)", и мне нужно видеть что пишет код.). И заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: `@echo off 
start python C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\13.py 
start python C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\14.py` так используйте старт+))

Comment: @Amgarak а есть возможность запустить их в разных окнах?

Comment: `start` python C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\13.py - я же вам уже написал. Во всяком случае у меня открывает в разных консолях+)

Comment: @Amgarak первый раз запустилось в одной, но сейчас всё работает как надо. спасибо большое!

Comment: [А с .exe можете тут повдохновляться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1561798/562052)