# Как конвертировать python файл с библиотеками из pip в exe

Tags: python, exe

У меня есть программа, в которой используется несколько библиотек из pip(customtkinter и Pillow) и изображения, нужно преобразовать её в exe файл. Я пробовал это делать через auto-py-to-exe, но при запуске вылезает ошибка.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'customtkinter'

Как это исправить?

Comment: Там в какой-то настройке вроде нужно указать нестандартные библиотеки, которые используются скриптом.

Comment: @CrazyElf Additional files, насколько помню.

Comment: если да, то в какой?

Comment: [Костыльный костыль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1561798/562052)

Answer (score 0):

Сам пользовался py-to-exe, но как я понял вам не подходит этот вариант. Еще есть вроде бы Pyinstaller в котором также можно преобразовать и сделать это так чтобы он работал у всех вроде бы.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole your_script.py
```

вот команда которую я нашел для преобразования.

Comment: насколько я знаю в Pyinstaller нельзя добавлять изображения, а мне они нужны

Comment: Там нужен флаг  --add-data "images/*;images/" где вы указываете путь к картинке(таких может быть флагов несколько если нужно)

Comment: @Kiraletka любые файлы можно добавлять.

Comment: я хз почему, но у меня просто не устанавливается pyinstaller

Comment: Можете написать ошибку или что-то еще, как вы определяете что не установилось