# Pyinstaller ошибка после компиляции. Pywin32

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.8, pywin32

Я скомпилировал свою программу через pyinstaller `pyinstaller -F main.py`, использующую pywin32 и все скомпилировалось отлично, но при запуске приложения в Windows Sandbox, для теста работы без установленного python - приложение выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py", line 25, in _pyi_rthook
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "win32com\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "pywintypes.py", line 126, in <module>
  File "pywintypes.py", line 116, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pywintypes: The specified module could not be found.
[884] Failed to execute script 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy' due to unhandled exception!
```

Я искал информацию про такую ошибку, но нашел лишь про ее, во время компиляции и там советовали обновить pywin32. Но это после компиляции - запуск .exe, на пк где нет python и по сути не требуется для запуска .exe

Comment: По всей видимости в сборку не добавился длл, на его отсутствие собственно и ругаются. `pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "[path to dll];." main.py `

Comment: [На крайний случай есть костыль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1561798/562052)

Comment: @Amgarak К сожалению, я пробовал такое и мне не помогло, я ищу решение без костылей. Но спасибо за ответ, это мне очень поможет с моей другой проблемой связанной с .pyd