# Ошибка при установке Python'а на ноутбук с виндовс 10

Tags: python

хотел установить python на ноутбук с виндовс10 но не тут то было,(до этого устанавливал на другой ноут с 11виндой и все было нормально)
пробовал по разному устанавливать и разные версии все бес толку,
реестр тоже чистил.

первая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вторая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вариант снести винду не подойдет,
пробовал все и подобные проблемы на разных форумах читал ничего не помогало
есть какие-нибудь предложения?
если нужна будет еще информация без проблем предоставлю

Дополнение1:
заметил следующие, если поместить установщик в корень диска ц и запустить от имени админа то выдает такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: От администратора пробовали ставить?

Comment: @CrazyElf само собой

Comment: Скачайте портативную версию как вариант.

Comment: @Amgarak как вариант можно попробовать

Comment: @Amgarak портативная версия это которая "Windows embeddable package (64-bit)"? верно

Comment: @oleg https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1561798/562052 вот можете посмотреть небольшую инструкцию для портативного питона. Собственно вам нужна только первая часть инструкции.

Comment: @Amgarak инструкция понятна, я поступил похожим образом если это можно так назвать, я с основного ноутбука взял папку с питоном и скопировал на второе устройство и в переменных средах добавил путь до питона