Python не работает корректно exe файл после компиляции
Эксперты, очень прошу Вашей помощи!
Сам решить задачу не в силах. Сделал небольшую программу для сотрудников, чтобы облегчить им работу - некий справочник, а также локальный сайт, который открывается внутри программы при помощи библиотеки pywebview (при других отображается некорректно) и чтобы он не блокировал работу программы использую отдельный поток при помощи multiprocessing.
Проблема в следующем: код работает так как нужно при запуске в IDE (через PyCharm), но после компиляции через auto-py-to-exe при нажатии на кнопку - он не запускает окно сайта, как должен - а запускает ещё одну копию самого приложения.
Подскажите, как исправить? Рабочие компьютеры могут запустить только exe файлы =(
Код для демонстрации примера. При компиляции проблема сохраняется:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import webview
import multiprocessing as mp

class Guide():
    def __init__(self):
        top = Frame(frame1, highlightbackground='#707070',
                         highlightthickness=1)
        bottom = Frame(frame1, background="white",
                            highlightbackground='#707070',
                            highlightthickness=1)
        top.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        bottom.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True, pady=[2, 0])
        btn_site = ttk.Button(frame1, text='Запустить',
                                   compound='left', command=self.run,
                              cursor='hand2')
        btn_site.pack(in_=top, side=RIGHT)

    def runners(self):
        webview.create_window('Справочник', 'https://www.google.com/',
                              width=1288, height=733, x=318, y=236,
                              zoomable=True, text_select=True)
        webview.start()

    def run(self):
        p = mp.Process(target=self.runners)
        p.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    notebook = ttk.Notebook()
    notebook.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

    frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    notebook.add(frame1, text='Справочник')

    guide = Guide()

    root.mainloop()


Скомпилируйте не в один файл, и проверьте полученную структуру проекта - все либы подтянулись или нет.

Даже данный код компилируется с ошибкой, разве это не означает - что проблема в другом? Тут же почти ничего нет, хотя ситуация аналогичная... Не знаю, как решить((

Если вас не очень пугают костыли, то можете воспользоваться:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1561798/562052

Меня не пугает ничего, для меня главное - работоспособность проекта =) Спасибо огромное, вижу помогли кому-то решать подобную проблему. Попробую на своём примере... Премного благодарен за помощь! =)
